# Why MinGW couldn't find memcpy?

Tags: windows-xp, mingw, autotools, memcpy, msys

I just installed MinGW + MSYS in Windows XP using graphical installer. Everything seems fine.

However, when I try to build a C++ application using `./configure, make, make install`, it shows error message. The following 2 checkings failed:

`AC_CHECK_LIB(m, memcpy, [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([error msg])])`

`AC_CHECK_FUNC(memcpy, [],[AC_MSG_ERROR([error msg])])`

Why my MinGW couldn't find `memcpy` and its library? Can anyone give me suggestion how to fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: What are the compile errors you're getting?

Comment: Also, a snippet from the config.log file around the error would be helpful (search for "memcpy" in the config.log file).

Answer (score 0):

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

Copy block of memory, copies the values of num bytes from the location pointed by source directly to the memory block pointed by destination.
For reference please see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

Comment: the question is not asking what memcpy is...